# Joining 3 Tables in xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am trying to join 3 tables in a view; here is the situation:

I have a table that contains information about person daily wages. I have another table that lists the Expenses, Income, Register (1 each ) for each Student. But each of these preferences is merely an ID Number and the ID Number. But I need to join them on User name

Pretty much, I have INNER JOIN on the table with their preferences, and their information, the result is something like...

```
  John  | Expense | 500 | Food
```

Where john would be the UserId. So Now I want to match that UserID to a third table where this table contains a UserID and Incomesalary.

So pretty much, I want my result to be like...

```
  John | Expense| 500 | Food| 10000(Income Salary)
```

Comment: I could not understand what is the matter with this question. why somebody putting negative vote always when I ask a question.

Comment: I am not the downvoter. If you would ask question straightforward without showing your related code and what you have tried. You should emphasize the exact problem. People would downvote if they find your question unclear.

Comment: okay. in here i need a idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if you are using xamarin or java, sqlite has always the same sql syntax.

It would be easier to help you, when your question contains more information, like all your tablenames and columns

```
SELECT
  first.usename,
  second.other,
  third.anotherother
FROM first
INNER JOIN second ON first.username = second.username
INNER JOIN third ON second.username = third.username;
```

You can find more informations in the documentation https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html